# HTMLPurifier Youtube

Tags: php, encoding, htmlpurifier

```
<?php

require_once '/library/HTMLPurifier/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

    $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();

    $config->set('Filter.YouTube', true);

        $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
?>
```

(^ This is my only settings for HTMLPurifier)

It should `<span class="youtube-embed">nto6EvPFO0Q</span>` make this in to a Youtube embbeded video. But it's not working. (Nothing happens simply)

But loading like this works:

```
<object width="425" height="350">
  <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/nto6EvPFO0Q />
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
  <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/nto6EvPFO0Q"
         type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
         wmode="transparent" width="425" height="350" />
</object>
```

(Is this a security issue? ^)

Comment: When you say: "The file is in ANSI format", do you mean CP-1252?

Comment: I changed to UTF-8. It's just the youtube problem. I am going to edit my question so its easier to understand.

Comment: I think you removed too much of the question. I don't see any åäö characters there.

Comment: @Juhana Well the problem is the Youtube embed :) I fixed the åöä!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use UTF-8. All other character sets are obsolete and should never be used except in legacy applications where you have no other choice.

Edit (after update of question):

First, you should use this:

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385"
 src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXIDXXXX" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Instead since it works on smart phones and the flash version doesn't.

Second, according to their documentation you need to download and include YouTube.php from http://repo.or.cz/w/htmlpurifier.git?a=blob;hb=HEAD;f=library/HTMLPurifier/Filter/YouTube.php (and when you do so update it to the new type of embed code).

Comment: I'd correct this to simply `UTF`. Any of the UTF family is fine, though yes, UTF-8 is the most common (for good reasons) for webpage encoding.

Comment: @MatthewScharley I wouldn't. UTF-16 has a horrible BOM in it which causes no end of trouble (try writing a configuration file in UTF-16 - or a shell script). UTF-32 gives no value for the space it wastes since combining marks (and composed characters) mean a single 32 bit value doesn't necessarily mean a single glyph so you gain no simplicity by using it.

Comment: I already have that files in my folders, thats why I am so confused it doesnt work (Its already included in the filter folder in the library folder that I downloaded)..

Comment: The embed seem to work only for Youtube, but I just want the user to type the span class, I've presented above (as it should be working)

Comment: Try putting some debug code in that file - just have it echo something when included (i.e. put the echo not in a function). Then add an echo when the functions are run.

Comment: @MatthewScharley The main problem about other UTF charsets is that they are very poorly supported in comparison to UTF-8.

Comment: I've tried changed the Youtube filter file, No result. Aren't there any updated version of that file?